# ZF2 module config service_manager add constructor param

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2, php

I've been searching and trying for a while now and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong...
I've been reading quite some documentation now and have tried a lot of different approaches.

I hope one of you guys can help me out..

My idea:
I have a module called Application. In this module there is an `\Application\Controller\IndexController` which is used to show the homepage of my application.
The IndexController needs an object with `\Zend\http\Client`, so I though I should use the factories key in the configuration that is returned by `\Application\Module->getServiceConfig()` and add a constructor with required param `\Zend\Http\Client $client`.

Unfortunatly this is not working..

My code:

```
<?php
// module/Application/Module.php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'IndexController' => function($serviceManager) {
                    $httpClient = \Zend\Http\Client;

                    return new IndexController($httpClient);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}

<?php
// module/Application/config/module.config.php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions' => true,
        'doctype' => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
        'exception_template' => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);

<?php
// module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $httpClient;

    public function __construct(\Zend\Http\Client $client)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $client;
    }

    public function getHttpClient()
    {
        return $this->httpClient;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {                
        $httpClient = $this->getHttpClient();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\IndexController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Http\Client, none given, called in /var/www/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170 and defined in /var/www/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `getControllerConfig` method in Module.php to do what you're asking, controllers have their own manager, remove what you have from getServiceConfig, and use the following instead

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => function($serviceManager) {
                $httpClient = new \Zend\Http\Client;
                return new \Application\Controller\IndexController($httpClient);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

You'll also need to remove the line from controller invokables in module.config.php since it'll conflict with your factory

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        // this line's no longer needed
        //'Application\Controller\Index'      => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
```